# Getting parameter of calling function with arguments.callee.caller

Tags: javascript, function, debugging

I wanted to improve my debug function to include information about the function that called debug().

I used **`arguments.callee.caller.name`** (`debug.caller.name` to be more precise) to get the name of the function that is calling debug().

Is there a way to get the parameter of the caller function?

Let's say i have this example:

```
function test(paramOne, paramTwo){
    debug();
}
```

and

```
function debug(){
    console.log("function "+debug.caller.name+": ");
    console.log("parameter: ");
    console.log(debug.caller.parameter); // does not work
    //(i expect an array at this point)
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the debugger of your browser ? It shows you everything you need about the call stack

Comment: Well that's why i use methodname.callee instead. That's not generic and not deprecated right?

Comment: @sebcap26 i use firebug with it's console mainly. the rest seems unclear (visually) to me, losing track of the important stuff. printing the entire object/function every time is a bit of an overload too. That's why i wanted a slim result with my own debugfunction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function.name is an experimental technology of ECMA 6--
it doesnt work in all browsers.   arguments.callee is deprecated but not caller

```
function test (param1,param2)   
  {
  debug  ();
  }

function debug ()
  {
  var caller=debug.caller;

  //-- get function name
  var RegExp_FuncName=new RegExp ("function.*(?=\\()");
  var RegExp_Space=new RegExp (" ","g");
  var name=caller.toString().match (RegExp_FuncName);
  name=name[0].replace (RegExp_Space,"");
  name=name.slice (8,name.length);
  if (name=="") name="anonymous";

  //-- get parameters
  var parameters=caller.arguments;

  var i,l=parameters.length, output;

  output=name;
  for (var i=0;i<l;i++)
    output+=" | "+parameters[i];

  alert (output);
  }

test (1,2);
```

Comment: you did a lot of tweaking that is not really needed in my opinion. if you have debug.caller you can just use debug.caller.name instead of using regex to get the entire function and slicing away stuff. `caller.arguments` is the key part that i needed.

Comment: the name property is experimental and doesnt work in all browsers
- read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

Comment: Ah now I understand! I will take your safe approach then. Ofc ie doesn't support that feature

Answer (score 2):

You should use `debug.caller.arguments` instead of `debug.caller.parameter`

Comment: this is exactly what i needed. i could not find an api/documentary that tells me which functions caller has. please share if you have a source for that.